# Showing that $\frac12\frac{d}{dt}\|f\|_{L^2} = \langle \partial_tf, f\rangle_{L^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Suppose $f = f(x,t)$ where $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ has support in a compact domain $D \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. I would like to prove the simple identity $$\frac12\frac{d}{dt}\|f\|_{L^2} = \langle \partial_tf, f\rangle_{L^2}.$$
Written more explicitly,
$$\frac12 \frac{d}{dt} \int_D |f(x,t)|^2dx = \int_D\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) \cdot f(x,t) dx \tag{1}$$

I know that in 1D this follows from the observation that $(f^2)' = 2ff'$, and the above can easily be proven by taking the derivative inside the integral. Embarrassingly, what is causing me trouble is the $| \cdot |$. Shouldn't we have
$$\frac12\frac{d}{dt} |f(x,t)|^2 = |f(x,t)|\frac{d}{dt}\Big(|f(x,t)|\Big)? \tag{2}$$
How is the right-hand side of (1) equal to the right-hand side of the integrand in (2)?

Comment: What you’ve written in (1) makes no sense. You need need a dot product of those vector-valued functions.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for catching both of those typos, I have corrected them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a dot product (in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ), denoted $\cdot $, in equation 1 and it should read
$$
\int_D  f(x,t) \cdot \partial_t f(x,t)  dx.
$$Furthermore, you can always just expand
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt}|f(x,t)|^2&=\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt}\sum_{i=1}^3 f_i(x,t)^2 \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^3 2f_i(x,t)\partial_t f_i(x,t) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^3 f_i(x,t) \partial_t f_i(x,t) \\
&= f(x,t) \cdot \partial_t f(x,t) .
\end{align*}
This should clear up how both (1) and (2) are equal.

Comment: Or, without coordinates, differentiate $\|f\|^2=f\cdot f$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome. Also, Ted Shifrin is right on the account that, in the long run, working coordinate-free becomes more important.